# A POSIX way to query sockaddr for private addresses

Tags: networking, posix

I'm confused as to how s_addr and s6_addr are organised after an accept().  Do I dare inet_ntop() and work with the resulting strings?

Looking for private address ranges...
10.*
172...
192.168.*
Extra credit for 127.*

Honestly I don't have a use case for fc00::/7, but someone might.

Here is my source...
https://github.com/cheako/ihlt/blob/master/src/server.c#L186

Comment: Actually, `127.0.0.0/8` is _not_ a private address range. For IPv4, there are only three private address ranges, as defined by RFC 1918: `10.0.0.0/8`, '172.16.0.0.0/12` (notice that not all `172.0.0.0/8` addresses fall into this, as you seem to imply), and `192.168.0.0/16`. There are many other ranges that cannot be routed on the public Internet, but they are simply _not_ private addresses. See the [IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml).

Comment: That's exactly why there should be an example... Somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

After much work and experimentation, I've devised the following and it seemed to work.

```
bool IsPrivate( in_addr_t t) {
    bool ret = false;
    in_addr_t a = t & (in_addr_t) 0xff;
    if( a == (in_addr_t) 0x7f ) ret = true;
    if( a == (in_addr_t) 0x0a ) ret = true;
    in_addr_t b = t & (in_addr_t) 0xe0ff;
    if( b == (in_addr_t) 0xac ) ret = true;
    in_addr_t c = t & (in_addr_t) 0xffff;
    if( c == (in_addr_t) 0xa8c0 ) ret = true;
    return ret;
}
```